# How can an app pool be recycled due to config changes whereas the applicationHost file isn't modified?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have a website which includes many web apps in IIS 7.5.

Today, two application pools were recycled twice "due to 1 or more configuration changes in the application pool properties" according the Event Viewer.

The thing is that nobody changed the configuration of these app pools. The applicationHost.config file wasn't modifed since several weeks...

Any idea why they were recycled?

Comment: What about web.config? Could that have been modified?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the applications' web.config were modified :-/